# How do I add a text for the 1st 30 seconds inside a filter_complex expression for each video part?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-processing

I am generating a video grid using the following filter_complex command

```
ffmpeg
     -i v_nimble_guardian.mkv -i macko_nimble_guardian.mkv -i ghost_nimble_guardian_1.mp4 -i nano_nimble_guardian.mkv
     -filter_complex "
         nullsrc=size=3840x2160 [base];
         [0:v] trim=start=39.117000,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=1920x1080 [upperleft];
         [1:v] trim=start=40.483000,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=1920x1080 [upperright];
         [2:v] trim=start=32.416471,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=1920x1080 [lowerleft];
         [3:v] trim=start=28.100000,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=1920x1080 [lowerright];
         [3:a] atrim=start=28.100000,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[outa];
         [base][upperleft] overlay=shortest=1 [tmp1];
         [tmp1][upperright] overlay=shortest=1:x=1920 [tmp2];
         [tmp2][lowerleft] overlay=shortest=1:y=1080 [tmp3];
         [tmp3][lowerright] overlay=shortest=1:x=1920:y=1080[v]
     "
     -map "[v]" -map "[outa]" -c:v libx264 -crf 17 -shortest -t 880 output4k.mkv
```

How do I text to this video grid that will appear with a fade in at 10 seconds, stay for 30 seconds and then fade out?

[image]

**What I tried?**

```
ffmpeg
     -i v.mkv -i macko_nimble_guardian.mkv -i ghost_nimble_guardian_subtle_arrow_1.mp4 -i nano_nimble_guardian.mkv
     -filter_complex "
         nullsrc=size=1920x1080 [base];
         drawtext=text='Summer Video':enable='between(t,10,30)'[fg];
         [0:v] trim=start=39.117000,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=960x540 [upperleft];
         [1:v] trim=start=40.483000,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=960x540 [upperright];
         [2:v] trim=start=32.416471,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=960x540 [lowerleft];
         [3:v] trim=start=28.100000,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=960x540 [lowerright];
         [3:a] atrim=start=28.100000,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[outa];
         [base][upperleft] overlay=shortest=1 [tmp1];
         [tmp1][upperright] overlay=shortest=1:x=960 [tmp2];
         [tmp2][lowerleft] overlay=shortest=1:y=540 [tmp3];
         [tmp3][lowerright] overlay=shortest=1:x=960:y=540[v]
     "
     -map "[v]" -map "[outa]" -c:v libx264 -shortest -t '30' output2.mkv
```

It gives me an error

```
[Parsed_drawtext_1 @ 0x600002bdc420] Using "/System/Library/Fonts/Supplemental/Verdana.ttf"
Filter drawtext:default has an unconnected output
```

Answer (score 1):

Add it after the final overlay,

`[tmp3][lowerright] overlay=shortest=1:x=1920:y=1080,drawtext=...[v]`

Comment: https://pastebin.com/LC2yYA4S gives an error: no such filter ''

Comment: same error on the other variation https://pastebin.com/A3tWr4sQ

Comment: Your first link shows `y=180[v];drawtext...`, but look at my example, it's `:y=1080,drawtext=...[v]`.  And where did the pad & fade come from? - they are not there in your Q. Also, afade will go after the last atrim and before `[outa]`

Answer (score 0):

```
ffmpeg
     -i v_nimble_guardian.mkv -i macko_nimble_guardian.mkv -i ghost_nimble_guardian_subtle_arrow_1.mp4 -i nano_nimble_guardian.mkv
     -filter_complex "
      nullsrc=size=3840x2160 [base];
      [0:v] trim=start=39.117000,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=1920x1080, drawtext=fontfile=control-freak-font/CONTF___.ttf:text='vivz_kestrel':fontsize=96:fontcolor=0xFFFFFF:alpha='if(lt(t,70),0,if(lt(t,75),(t-70)/5,if(lt(t,105),1,if(lt(t,110),(5-(t-105))/5,0))))':x=w-text_w-36:y=h-text_h-36 [upperleft];
      [1:v] trim=start=40.483000,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=1920x1080, drawtext=fontfile=control-freak-font/CONTF___.ttf:text='LoftierTundra72':fontsize=96:fontcolor=0xFFFFFF:alpha='if(lt(t,70),0,if(lt(t,75),(t-70)/5,if(lt(t,105),1,if(lt(t,110),(5-(t-105))/5,0))))':x=w-text_w-36:y=h-text_h-36 [upperright];
      [2:v] trim=start=32.416471,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=1920x1080, drawtext=fontfile=control-freak-font/CONTF___.ttf:text='Ghost_141989':fontsize=96:fontcolor=0xFFFFFF:alpha='if(lt(t,70),0,if(lt(t,75),(t-70)/5,if(lt(t,105),1,if(lt(t,110),(5-(t-105))/5,0))))':x=w-text_w-36:y=h-text_h-36 [lowerleft];
      [3:v] trim=start=28.1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=1920x1080, drawtext=fontfile=control-freak-font/CONTF___.ttf:text='nano_machine':fontsize=96:fontcolor=0xFFFFFF:alpha='if(lt(t,70),0,if(lt(t,75),(t-70)/5,if(lt(t,105),1,if(lt(t,110),(5-(t-105))/5,0))))':x=w-text_w-36:y=h-text_h-36 [lowerright];
      [3:a] atrim=start=28.1,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[outa];
      [base][upperleft] overlay=shortest=1 [tmp1];
      [tmp1][upperright] overlay=shortest=1:x=1920 [tmp2];
      [tmp2][lowerleft] overlay=shortest=1:y=1080 [tmp3];
      [tmp3][lowerright] overlay=shortest=1:x=1920:y=1080[v]
     "
     -map "[v]" -map "[outa]" -c:v libx264 -shortest 100_100_hardcore_grfs_coop_pc_nimble_guardian.mp4
```

The answer above does the trick. The idea is to use drawtext on each video stream. Set a custom font for it, fontsize. The position is explained in detail [HERE](https://superuser.com/a/939386/807492) The alpha effect can be generated with a [tool](https://ffmpeg.shanewhite.co) The idea here is that the text starts a fade in at 70, completes it at 75, stays for another 30 seconds, starts a fade out and then completes it 5 seconds later